# Manifest merger failed (After deleting a few files)

Tags: android

I tried adding some new activities to my project, but had to delete them for some reasons. And then my project started giving **Manifest merger failed**
error. I did not update any thing as such.

I get the following error :

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.quickstart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Google Sheets API Android Quickstart"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="GBL"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".NotificationService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quickstart"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev523-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I know this question has been asked tons of times but none of the answers seemed to help me a lot. Any help appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Set this manifest file :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="fase"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Google Sheets API Android Quickstart"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="GBL"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service android:name=".NotificationService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies must all use the same version of the support library.

Try changing the following line **`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'`**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev523-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Also, this is why you should use source control (git). When you run into an issue, you can just reset your repository to the last known working state.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

Removing the above lines did the trick, thanks everyone for their time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what your error says. Add 'tools:replace="android:value" to your manifest like so:

```
<application
     ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value">

   ...

</application>
```